# How to connect to neo4j on remote server using cytoscape neo4j plugin

Tags: neo4j, cytoscape

I installed cytoscape 3.8.2 and Cytoscape Neo4j Plugin (http://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/cytoscapeneo4jplugin). I've generated a small neo4j graph, which is situated on a remote server.

When trying to connect to neo4j using the plugin I get following error: "Cannot connect to neo4j"

What am I doing wrong? Is it not possible to connect to neo4j when the instance is situated on a remote server?

Answer (score 0):

It certainly should work, but since Neo4J uses it's own port, which isn't opened by default on most hosts, you may need to tweak your server firewall.

-- scooter

Comment: Thanks, I believe the bolt protocol is used, in which case the default port 7687 is used, most likely only the one for the browser 7474 is open. I just tried the following: i forwarded 7687 by SSH to localhost. Afterwards  I could establish a connection to neo4j with localhost as 'host'. Let's see what it gives if 7687 is open!

Comment: works when opening 7687 (btw used ports are mentioned in the neo4j.conf file, where you can also adjust them)!